# Show that standard (order) topology on $\mathbb{N}$ and the floor topology on $\mathbb{N}$ are the same.

Tags: general-topology

Show that standard (order) topology on $\mathbb{N}$ and the floor topology on $\mathbb{N}$ are the same.

I know that order topology is generated by the subbasis that consists of positive and negative open rays, and floor topology is generated by the basis which gives a half open interval. Notation for both the topologies are listed below:

Standard (order) topology: $S$ = {$(-\infty, b)| $b $\in X$} U {$(a,\infty)| a \in X$}, where S is the sub-basis.
Floor or lower limit topology: $B_l$ = {$[a,b)| a,b \in X,a < b$}.

Now, if I consider the set of natural numbers, i.e. $\mathbb{N}$ , then its this set: {0,1,2,....}. Now, if I take $[0,1)$ or [2,3) or [4,7) etc, how do I show that its the same?

Need some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the discrete topology on $\Bbb N$: $\{n\} = (n-1,n+1)$ for $n>1$, and $\{0\}=(-\infty,1)$ for the order topology, and $\{n\}=[n,n+1)$ for the floor topology, e.g.

Comment: I think this looks good, I have used your idea and constructed several examples. I am sure this will work fine, but I have a question: Since you said that ${0}$ = $(-\infty, 1)$, does this mean that its sub-basis is going to be $(-\infty, 0)$ U $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun No, I just said that $\{0\}$ is a subbasic open set (because it can be seen as an open ray). "constructed several examples?" A proof is not a set of examples. What do you mean?